# Symfony 2 - Odd behavior dispatching an event and global variables

Tags: php, symfony

I'm **dispatching** a simple event plugged to a simple **listener** in Symfony 2.

**Event**

```
class MyDocumentEvent extends Event {
    private $document;

    public function __construct(\Namespace\Document $document)
    {
        $this->document = $document;
    }

    public function getDocument()
    {
        return $this->document;
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
/**
 * @DI\Service("core.document.insert", public=true)
 * @DI\Tag("kernel.event_listener", attributes={"event"="document.insert.event", "method"="onEventReceived"})
 * NB This is equivalent to declaring a service in services.yml (DIExtraBundle is awesome by the way)
 */
class MyListener
{
    public function onEventReceived(MyDocumentEvent $event)
    {
        $document = $event->getDocument();
        // $aaa = $event->getDocument(); // is the same

        // perform stuff on $document or $aaa

        $document->setLabel("This makes me crazy!");
        // $aaa->setLabel(); // is the same
        return;
    }
}
```

And very oddly in my controller, the Document entity is modified magically *as if* the `$document` was a global variable!

**Controller test code**

```
$dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

$document = new \Namespace\Document();
$document->setLabel('unit.test.document.insert');

$event = new MyDocumentEvent($document);
$dispatcher->dispatch('document.insert.event', $event);

echo $document->getLabel(); // RETURNS "This makes me crazy!"
```

This really disturbs me. Why does Symfony 2 have this behaviour ?

Is that normal or i'm just doing a big architectural mistake here ? I kinda of excpected i'd have to add getters and setters from the listener back to the event to get my modified entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP all objects are passed by reference by default (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). So there is no magic in Symfony's code.

This is basically what you do:

- create object (`$document = new \Namespace\Document();`)
- pass it's reference to event's constructor (`$event = new
  MyDocumentEvent($document);`)
- when event is dispatched you call getter which returns reference to
  your object (`return $this->document;`)
- then you modify object (`$document->setLabel("This makes me
  crazy!");`)
- by accessing object you use same reference and see
  already changed object.

Comment: I'm sure there is no magic. How does that in any way explain this behavior ?

Comment: I've added some more clarifications.

Comment: Still not clear. The document variable is never passed back to the event. You can write $aaa in MyListener instead of $document which still give the same result... So thats not it.

Comment: It's the same object, does not matter how you name the variable :) you can verify it with http://php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-object-hash.php function. Try it on different parts of your code and you'll get same hash.

Comment: And if this is the bug its completely contrary to everything i'v been tough in the last 9 years ! :p (if you look just at the controller...)

Comment: Please take a look at simplified example: http://3v4l.org/DgL7l it's same what happens in your case.

Comment: And it's not a bug, it's the way how PHP handles objects :)

Comment: I have to admit you were right... ;-). What do you think about the architecture of my code, in general. I'm i making a mistake ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83767/discussion-between-mantas-and-romain-bruckert).